# Order/Sort/Rank a table

Tags: r

I have a table like this

`table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)`

I want to rank the rows by the ones with more observations in the 4 cylinder. E.g.

```
     4  6  8
  4  8  4  0
  5  2  1  2
  3  1  2 12
```

I have been playing with order/sort/rank without much success. How could I order tables output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert `table` to `data.frame` and then `order` by the column.

```
sort_col <- "4"
tab <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl))
tab[order(-tab[sort_col]), ]
# OR tab[order(tab[sort_col], decreasing = TRUE), ]

#  4 6  8
#4 8 4  0
#5 2 1  2
#3 1 2 12
```

---

If we don't want to convert it into data frame and want to maintain the `table` structure we can do

```
tab <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)
tab[order(-tab[,dimnames(tab)[[2]] == sort_col]),]

#     4  6  8
#  4  8  4  0
#  5  2  1  2
#  3  1  2 12
```

Comment: Sure, that's the usual way but I was thinking on a one-liner using `table` nested into another function ;-)

Comment: @user3507584 not a one-liner but managed to get something keeping it within `table` but it is ugly :P

Answer (score 1):

Could try this. Use `sort` for the relevant column, specifying `decreasing=TRUE`; take the `names` of the sorted rows and subset using those.

```
table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)[names(sort(table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)[,1], dec=T)), ]

     4  6  8
  4  8  4  0
  5  2  1  2
  3  1  2 12
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same scope as Milan, but using the `order()` function, instead of looking for `names()` in a `sort()`-ed list.
The `[,1]` is to look at the first column when ordering.

```
table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)[order(table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$cyl)[,1], decreasing=T),]
```